# Nginx not starting as a Windows Service

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to run nginx as a service on windows 8 but i'm unable to start it as a service. 
I don't see any error in the logs after running .\nginx -c conf\nginx.windows.conf in the powershell.
Cursor keeps on blinking after i run this command.
nginx.exe is still running in the task manager as process but I can't find it under services.[taskmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugbro.png)

I've spent a lot of time on this. Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Share relevant nginx logs if available. What's in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Here's similar question [how to add nginx.exe as system service like apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061191/how-to-add-nginx-exe-as-system-service-like-apache) with answer that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

nginx does not support running as a service [under Windows](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html). I can't imagine any reason why you'd want to anyway, since [you won't be using it in production](https://serverfault.com/a/469526/126632).

Comment: To provide a demo or test site for remote users perhaps?